# How execute job only in the main database in a mult tenant project?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I have a project that when my user makes a registration my project is connected by default to my main database the public schema.

And when the user successful make a registration I make an event to send an email, here is my Listener to the event:

```
class WelcomeNewCompanyListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle($event)
    {

        $data = array (
            'name' =>  $event->company['name'],
            'email' =>  $event->company['email'],
        );

        $beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
        $beautymail->send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message
                ->from('contato@44online.com.br', '44 Online')
                ->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
                ->subject('Bem vindo a 44 Online!');
        });
    }
}
```

It is working fine when I use the same schema like the public, but if I make a request that needs to change the schema for a tenant and the user makes a ResetPasswordEvent per example.

My project changes the connection in a middleware here:

```
 public function reconnect($companyInfo) {    

      DB::purge('tenant');
      Config::set('database.connections.tenant.schema', $companyInfo[0]->db_schema);
      DB::reconnect('tenant'); 
      Schema::connection('tenant')->getConnection()->reconnect();

   }
```

The problem is when a user makes a ResetPasswordEvent my project make a job, but he is making on the database from the tenant, not for the main table I try to put a reconnect after the handle but is not working, it insists in inserting the job in the database from the tenant. What should I do?

When I make this connection in handle on

```
      DB::purge('tenant');
      Config::set('database.connections.tenant.schema', 'public');
      DB::reconnect('tenant'); 
      Schema::connection('tenant')->getConnection()->reconnect();
```

I getting this failed job and I don't use any connection

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "qu_users" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "qu_users" where "qu_users"."users_id" is null...
                      ^ in
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jobs might/should run in another process changing the default driver is lost
(Which does not seem to good idea to me anyway)

But anyway if you want your job to use a different database. in the handle
you need to pass it constructor of the job.. like new Job('tenant') / App::make(MyJob::class, ['connectionName' => 'tenant']);

This way the connection name should be available in the handle(), and you can change connection after entering the handle() function.

It will need the main connection in the beginning, as your queue workers, are probably running on that connection anyway.

Comment: As jobs might/should run in another process changing the default driver is lost (Which does not seem to good idea to me anyway). I dont understsnd what you say here, i dont know if job must run in the main database or in another? because the queue work only on one database right?